# A non-parametric test on SAS

Tags: statistics, sas

I have a small dataset consisting of three distinct observations on each of three variables, say x1 x2, x3 and the accompanying response y, on which I would like to perform Analysis of Variance to test whether the means are equal.

```
data anova;
input var obs resp;
cards;
1 1 1.1
1 2 .5 
1 3 -2.1
2 1 4.2
2 2 3.7
2 3 .8
3 1 3.2
3 2 2.8
3 3 6.3
;

proc anova data=anova;
class var;
model resp=var;
run;
```

All good so far. Now however, I would like to use a permutation test to check the p-value of the F-statistic. The test is quite simple and it consists of randomly reassigning the 9 observations to the 3 variables so that each variable has three observations, and calculating the F-statistic each time. The p-value would then be the proportion of these statistics that are higher than 4.39, the value of the F-test from the code above.

Normally I would do it by hand but there is 1680 possible combinations(  9!/(3!3!3!)  )here so it would take me a week. Is there a more elegant way to accomplish this? Perhaps a way to wrap this procedure in a loop or a function?

I would be grateful for your help, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my approach. It employs the `allperm` routine of SAS to populate all permutations. Then in order to eliminate duplicates, I use the product of the numbers in a group as the key. The result is 1680.

After this, you can use `by` keyword of `proc glm` to run based on the group indicator `group` in the final data set.

```
proc transpose data=anova(keep=resp) out=anova1;
run;
quit;

data anova1;
    set anova1;
    n = fact(9);
    array rs (*) col1-col9;
    do i=1 to n;
        call allperm(i, of rs(*));
        a = rs(1)*rs(2)*rs(3);
        b = rs(4)*rs(5)*rs(6);
        c = rs(7)*rs(8)*rs(9);
        file resperms notitles;
        put rs(*) a b c;
    end;
run;

data perms;
    infile resperms;
    input x1-x3 y1-y3 z1-z3 a b c;
run;

proc sort data=perms nodupkey;
    by a b c;
run;

data perms;
    set perms;
    group = _N_;
    drop a b c;
run;

proc transpose data=perms out=perms;
    by group;
run;
quit;

data perms;
    set perms;
    var = substr(_NAME_,1,1);
    obs = substr(_NAME_,2,1)*1;
    rename col1=resp;
    drop _NAME_;
run;
```

Comment: @JohnK For the rest, you can refer Jake's answer, starting from `proc glm`. Replace `replicate` with `group` and remove `weight` statement then do the final statistics. I just want to show you how  the combinations can be generated.

Comment: You need to tell us what issue you have run into. The code will give 1680 groups/combinations which is just you want. I tested it. Then it is using `by` of `proc glm` like Jake has mentioned. Also, spend some time reading the doc on `proc glm`. The combination generation is a hard part but model running is not.

Comment: No. it is `class var` and `by group`, not `class group`. group is the combination group number, while class is the anova group.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will study all these statements carefully.

Answer (score 2):

Resampling like this can be done with a few steps.  First, [following an example from SAS help](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/sqlproc/63043/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n082a03omu3i21n1k889zfklh4ps.htm), use PROC SQL to create a table with all the possible combinations of var and resp.

```
PROC SQL;
 CREATE TABLE possibilities AS SELECT a.var, b.resp FROM
  anova a CROSS JOIN anova b;
QUIT;
```

Then, resample from all the possible combinations of var and resp using PROC SURVEYSELECT.

```
PROC SURVEYSELECT
 DATA = possibilities
 OUT = permutations
 METHOD = URS  /* URS means unrestricted sampling, or sampling uniformly with
                  replacement */
 SAMPSIZE = 9  /* Generate samples that are the same size as your original 
                  data */
 REP = 1000;   /* Repeat 1000 times */
 STRATA var / ALLOC = PROP;  /* Make sure that we sample evenly from each of the
                                3 values of var */
RUN;
```

Then, using PROC GLM with a BY statement, calculate the F statistic for each replicate.

```
/* Data must be sorted to use a BY statement */
PROC SORT
 DATA = permutations;
 BY replicate;
RUN;
PROC GLM
 DATA = permutations
 NOPRINT
 OUTSTAT = f_statistics;
 CLASS var;
 MODEL resp = var;
 BY replicate;
 WEIGHT numberhits;
QUIT;
```

Finally, in a data step, create a dummy variable indicating whether each F statistic is greater than 4.39, the test statistic from the example, and then use the MEANS procedure to get the fraction of times that was true.  The final answer should be approximately 0.068, as in the original example.

```
DATA final;
 SET f_statistics;
 IF f ne .;  /* Drop rows of the GLM output that don't contain an F statistic */
 reject_null = (f > 4.39);
RUN;

PROC MEANS
 DATA = final
 MEAN;
 VAR reject_null;
RUN;
```

Comment: Yep, whenever possible in SAS use the BY statement to run things multiple times.  Very powerful and much faster both to run and to code than a big macro loop or similar.

Comment: Thank you but there might be a conceptual mistake in the above. I do not want to sample with replacement but without. Each observation should have an equal chance of being selected and once it is selected it can no longer be chosen. The resulting p-value should not vary. It should be constant no matter how many times you run the test. I believe the correct answer here is 0.071.